# The TimestampPath parameter does not reference an input value

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a lambda function that passes JSON to a step function. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "reminder": {
    "date": "2020-06-12T04:25:12.698Z",
    "to": "ilrein@hotmail.com",
    "from": "ilia.reingold@gmail.com",
    "subject": "hello world",
    "content": "lorem ipsum"
  }
}
```

My step function looks for `$.reminder.date` during one of its states:

[image]

As you can see, it has the relevant JSON input at the `ExecuteOn` state.

However, unexpectedly, it results an error attempting to read the variable:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your picture, it seems your input to `ExecuteOn` is a JSON-deserizable string, not a JSON object. Hence, the StepFunction doesn't know how to get `$.reminder.date` from this string.

You should make sure the upstream Lambda passes a JSON object to this StepFunction.